# Bose - Einstein integral together with Lorentzian distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, integration, bose-einstein-condensate

I am wondering whether it is possible to solve the following integral:
$$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega \frac{1}{e^{\beta\hbar\omega}-1}\frac{1}{(\omega-\omega_0)^2+\frac{\gamma^2}{4}}$$
The first therm is Bose-Einstein distribution, the second term is Lorentzian distribution with very small width $\gamma\ll\omega_0$. I tried to compute it using residue theorem, but the problem is that Bose-Einstein distribution is not a simple polynomial, so I do not know how to obtain its order. I have a big suspicion that this integral might be actualy infinity because of the singularity at $\omega=0$.
Any advice?

Comment: Yes. Your integral does not converge. What are you *actually* trying to calculate?

Comment: I try to calculate rate equation of mean value of photons inside a cavity. Time derivative of that value equals to a decay term plus this integral, which comes originally from noise term in Langevin equation. The lorentzian is here because photon creation annihilation operators are defined in cavity as the integral over lorentzian lineshape.

Comment: You  need to restrict the integral to positive frequencies.  What is wrong with approximating the Lorentzian as a delta function if $\gamma\ll \omega_0$?

Comment: That is a very good idea indeed! Thank you!

Comment: @mikestone I think this integral should be convergent because the principal integral of the Bose-Einstein distribution function near $\omega \sim 0$ vanishes, although I don't know the precise analytical expression of this integral...

Comment: The Bose distribution involves $d^nk/(2\pi)^n$ with $\omega=c|k|$. The integral the OP probably wants has $n=3$  and is  convergent at $\omega=0$. In $n=1$ I doubt that a principal part integral has any physical content -- especially as it should be $|\omega|$ and the "P" prescription requires $\omega$ not $|\omega|$.